# Excel sum-formula

Tags: excel-formula, sum

is there a nicer and more compact way to write this formula in Excel?

=SUM(MAX(0,H4-B4),MAX(0,H5-B5),MAX(0,H6-B6),MAX(0,H7-B7),MAX(0,H8-B8),MAX(0,H9-B9))

I tried to write it like this:

=SUM(MAX(0,H4:H9-B4:B9))

But that is not the identical term. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX accepts arrays as entry and will return the max of all the entries and not compare each to 0.  so the Max will return only one number to sum.  We need a different approach.

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((H4:H9-B4:B9>0)*(H4:H9-B4:B9))
```